# SQL Server 2012 Express Connection Timeout Expired

Tags: connection-timeout, sql-server-2012-express, handshake

[Error Message Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixz6S.jpg)

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express from scratch, but it is not working. Same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server **Express** will install as a named `SQLEXPRESS` instance - so you need to use your IP address with `\SQLEXRPESS` added to it as your server name:

```
Server Name: 192.168.1.199\SQLEXPRESS
```

**Update:** you need to go to SQL Server Configuration Manager and find out what your instance name is.

```
Start Menu 
   > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
        > Configuration Tools 
             > SQL Server 2012 Configuration Manager
```

You should see a screen something like this:

[image]

Find the entry for **SQL Server** that is in the "running" state - what does it say in the brackets after `SQL Server`? That's your instance name - if it's a default SQL Server Express installation, it should say `SQLEXPRESS`. If it doesn't - well then that's your instance name right there (unless when it's `MSSQLSERVER` - then it's the unnamed instance).

Use `192.168.1.199\instance-name` as your server name